# Angular - menu doesn't work on IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener

I'm working with Javascript menu which loads onInit on my angular app, it works fine on Chrome, but not on IE Edge and Firefox.

The code on my typescript file was:

```
ngOnInit() {
   //getmenu items
$(document).ready(function() {
  //addclasses to menu, etc.. 
});
```

So, after debugging I got to a point where I think I found the solution, which is adding an event listener instead of document.ready.

Now it's where things get confusing, if i add eventlistener:

```
ngOnInit() {
//getmenu items
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
//addclasses to menu, etc.. 
});
```

When I first load the app ( login page -> redirect where menu page is ) it doesn't work, but if I hit f5 and reload the page without login, it works, only on firefox .. on IE doesn't work. but if i change:

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function ()
```

to

```
 window.addEventListener('focus', function ()
```

it doesn't work on firefox and chrome ( the submenu flicks) but works on IE, after refreshing the page, as I said on the first time.

So, the question is, is there any type of event listener that works on every browser? Or do I have to refresh the page every time, if I log in? I know the question is a little confusing. Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

Comment: Did you checked your `pollyfills.ts`? every thing is properly imported ??

Comment: I have core-js/es6/* (stuff like set, map, date, symbol etc.. )  imported, core-js/es6/reflect, core-js/es7/reflect  and zone.js/dist/zone

Answer (score 3):

addEventListener works on most browsers - see https://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener

It may be because you are firing it too early try this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    //addclasses to menu, etc.. 
  });
}
```

EDIT:

Further to our discussion in comments, if you want to delay execution more:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {

    const condition = window.addEventListener
    if (condition) {
      // fire any code you want to when condition is met
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        //addclasses to menu, etc.. 
      });
      clearInterval(interval) // stop firing the code
    }
  }, 100) // fire the code every 100ms
}
```

Not sure exactly what you want to achieve, what your condition is or what code you want to execute when the condition is met, but this pattern of delaying code execution is easy to follow if you know what the condition is.

Comment: Changed to ngAfterViewInit, the problmes persists, but now it i hit f5 or crtl+f5 on any browser the menu starts to work.. you're right it because im loading the js to early.. but how can i delay that?

Comment: you can delay execution of JS but wrapping the JS in setInterval which will keep firing until some condition is met. I'll add an example to this post.

Comment: i've tryed setInterval of 3 seconds and the execute the JS code, the problem persists.. i don't know  why or what that happens. 
it works on every browser if i reload the page to ip:port/ or url/ 
it's like the menu only works after reload the page to raw url..

i can post my TS code if you want..

Answer (score 1):

I know hagner, im working always with onInit, and works fine, on this case i think im firing to early the JS function on init.
Let me put things this way:

When i login i go to the dashboard, it means; ip:port/dashboard
now i give you this: it works on every browser if i reload the page to ip:port/ 
why??

(doesn't work on IE if i hit f5 (ip:port/dashboard), only if i reaload to ip:port/

here's my tipescript code: it has all the code that pushes and produces menu, and clicks of menu, submenu and if clicked inside or outside etc..

**menu.compontent.ts:**

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
    private sub: any;
    public menu;
    public arr;
    showMenu = '';

  constructor(private _menu: MenuService,
              private router: Router) {}
ngOnInit() {

      let times = 0;
      if( times === 0)
      {
this._menu.getMenu()
          .subscribe( res => {
              let data = res;

              console.log(data);
              this.arr = data;
              this.arr = (<any>Object).values(data);
              console.log(this.arr );
              //debugger;
              times ++; //only push json wich contains menu one time!!
          });
       }
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
"use strict";

          $('.menu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
          //Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI

          $('.menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
          //Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu (thanks Luka Kladaric)

          $(".menu > nav > div > a").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\"><i class='icon-mod-mais fs1'></i></a>");
$(".menu > ul > li").click(function(e) {
              if ($(window).width() > 943) {
                  if ($(this).children('.menu-list').is(":visible")){
                      $(this).children('.menu-list').fadeToggle(15);
                      $(this).children('.menu-list').toggleClass('center');
                      e.preventDefault();
                  } else {
                      $('.menu-list').hide();
                      $('.menu-list').removeClass('center');
                      $(this).children('.menu-list').fadeToggle(15);
                      $(this).children('.menu-list').toggleClass('center');
                      e.preventDefault();
                  }
              }
          });

          $("body").click(function(e) {
              var target = e.target.className;
              if (target.indexOf("menu-button") == -1  ) {
                  $('.menu-list').hide();
                  $('.menu-list').removeClass('center');
                  return;
              }
          });
$(".menu > ul > li").click(function() {
              if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
                  $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(100);
              }
          });
          //If width is less or equal to 943px dropdowns are displayed on click (thanks Aman Jain from stackoverflow)

          $(".menu-mobile").click(function(e) {
              $(".menu > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
              e.preventDefault();
          });
//If menu a clicked stay active
          $(".menu > ul > li > a").click(function() {
 if($( this ).hasClass( "active" )) {
                  $(this).removeClass("active");
              }else {
                  $(".menu > ul > li > a").removeClass("active");
                  $(this).addClass("active");
              }
          });
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already working with the OnInit lifecycle hook. Different lifecycle hooks are called by Angular when the component is created/updated/destroyed and allows you to act on the events. The Angular framework ensures that these events works in all major browsers. For your use case you do not need to use any separate event listener within the ngOnInit method, you can use the ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit method to do all the work needed when a component is created. For more information you can read about Angular lifecycle hooks [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).